# SQL: partial group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Here's what my table `TheTable` looks like

```
ColA  | ColB  | ColC
------+-------+------
abc   | 2005  | item7
abc   | 2010  | item3
def   | 2009  | item2
def   | 2010  | item4
def   | 2011  | item5
def   | 2012  | item1
```

And I want to write a query to return this result:

```
ColA  | ColB  | ColC
------+-------+------
abc   | 2010  | item3
def   | 2012  | item1
```

I ended up with:

```
SELECT TheTable.ColA,TheTable.ColB,TheTable.ColC
FROM TheTable,(SELECT ColA a,MAX(ColB) b FROM TheTable GROUP BY ColA) t
WHERE t.a=TheTable.ColA AND t.b=TheTable.ColB
```

But I'm not sure this kind of nested query is very efficient. So the question is, is there a better way?

Comment: Your two other columns happen to both be MAX. What happens if you add a row with `def | 2008 | item7` and another with `def | 2012 | item3`? (Or change the latter to `2013` if `ColA,ColB` is unique.

Comment: The order of ColC is irrelevant. I changed the example to make it clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH OrderedTable AS
(
    SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ColA ORDER BY ColB DESC) AS Row
    FROM TheTable
)
SELECT ColA, ColB, ColC FROM OrderedTable WHERE Row = 1
```

Comment: Well, it only does one table scan (yours requires two), and also guarantees only one result when ColA and ColB are not unique, while yours will generate repeat results if a given ColA has more than one entry sharing the same Max(ColB). Your query may still perform better in some situations - mine requires a full sort of the table which (depending on indexes and volumes) may not be friendly.